# generating django rest framework server from swagger specs

Tags: server, django-rest-framework, code-generation, swagger-2.0

Is there any package to generate django rest framework server code from [swagger 2.0](https://swagger.io) specs as like one we have for flask [swagger-flask-server-generator](https://github.com/guokr/swagger-py-codegen).

Comment: I see there is no answer here. Were you able to figure out a way to stub a Django REST server from a Swagger/OpenAPI Spec file?

Comment: @BrylieChristopherOxley we internally developed a tool to automate this stub generation and lot more

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this GitHub project:

[Swagger Django Generator](https://github.com/praekelt/swagger-django-generator) by [Praekelt Consulting](http://www.praekelt.com/)